Block Specific Domains From History
Some websites create a TON of new history entries as you click around--I'm thinking social media sites like Facebook. If I go clicking around through someone's photos I can wind up with dozens of new entries that clog up looking through my history, add no value, and generally make my history less useful.
I get that I could use Incognito Mode, or Browser Profiles. The problem is that when I'm in Facebook also sometimes I want to click on peoples' links and read the articles they're sharing. And that can be useful history for me to have.
I also get that I could just clear my browser history, but unless I can easily set up an automatic process for this it's a pita for me to remember that every time.
Maybe there's a better way for me to manage this--have all links open in a different browser profile or something, but right now I'm thinking the most likely option is for me to find some extension or buried setting that allows me to just not add Facebook URLs to the history. Anyone have any suggestions? Currently using Chrome, although I'm not 100% against Firefox or Safari if they offer better solutions.

You can try the following add-on for Chrome: Autodelete History by Keywords or URL. According to its description:

Auto-delete your browser history & downloads based on custom keywords.
Sometimes Incognito just isn't enough. This extension will automatically delete sites in your browser history based on keywords you specify.
Never be embarrassed by your browser history again!
Just enter the keywords you want to be deleted on the settings page. If you visit a site with any of those keywords in the title or URL it won't show in your browser history. Downloads that match those keywords will also be automatically removed from your history (but the file won't be deleted).

However, it seems to allow only 2 keywords/URLs unless you upgrade.
